# how to reset your counter if a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a counter that counts if a button  is clicked the first time, and if it clicked the second time it decrements the counter, what I am trying to achieve is that if I click another button on the page it must reset my counter back to its original state meaning that it should start all over from the first click.

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
  if ($('#reset').click(function () {
    
        $('#notify').removeClass("notification");
        $("#notify").empty();
       
        counter = 0;
               
            }));
}



$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  $(this).data('increment', !$(this).data('increment'));
       
        if ($(this).data('increment'))
            counter++;
        else
            counter--;
        
        count();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button class="btn" >
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify" ></span>
</br>
</br>
<button id="reset"> Reset Counter</button>
```

as you can see from above if I click the "click me" buttons it will add to the counter,if I click all 4 button first  and then if I click on ONE of the "click me" buttons for the second time it will decrease the counter to 3, now when I click the reset button and then click "click me" it shows -1, I am trying to reset the counter  so it starts all over again from one on reset, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the data attribute that way will not actually put the `data-increment` to the buttons, you have to use `attr()` method for that, otherwise `$(this).data('increment')` won't know about it. Also, you don't have to use an if statement for event handling and doesn't need to be in a function. `<br/>` should have the `/` at the end and not at the start. See the working snippet below:

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
}

$('#reset').click(function() {
  $('#notify').removeClass("notification");
  $("#notify").empty();
  $('.btn').attr('data-increment', 'increment');
  counter = 0; // i tried to reset the counter here but it doesnt work
});

$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  if ($(this).attr('data-increment') == 'increment') {
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter--;
  }
  $(this).attr('data-increment', $(this).attr('data-increment') == 'increment' ? 'decrement' : 'increment');
  count();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button class="btn" data-increment='increment'>
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn" data-increment='increment'>
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn" data-increment='increment'>
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn" data-increment='increment'>
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="reset"> Reset Counter</button>
```

Comment: but this doesnt decrement my counter on second click,like how i have it in mine

Comment: @lonut, i cant add data-increment=increment to the buttons,because the buttons only get populated after the page loads dynamically, thats why its giving me -1 values and only after i click reset does the data-increment get added,i edited your answer so you see what i mean

Comment: Then why don't you add those data attributes when page loads/when you create the elements using jQuery?! It's not like there's a rule not to add them then. I've just made you an example that works, the rest I think you can handle yourself.

Comment: Thats what i am going to do,thought you would know off a different way off doing it instead of me doing it that way but Thank you,this helped

Answer (score 3):

When you click reset you want to reset the data variable of all of the buttons to true, meaning they will increment when next clicked. So add this inside your reset code:

```
$(this).data('increment', true);
```

At the moment they're simply keeping their previous state and therefore decreasing the count if they were last incremented.

EDIT:
Try this, it's working for me.

```
<html>

<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var counter = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
        function count() {
            $('#notify').addClass("notification");
            $("#notify").html(counter);
            if ($('#reset').click(function () {
                $('.btn').attr('data', true);
            $('#notify').removeClass("notification");
                        $("#notify").empty();
                    counter=0; // i tried to reset the counter here but it doesnt work

                    }));
        }



        $('.btn').click(function(e) {
            if ($(this).attr('data') == 'true') {
                counter++;
                $(this).attr('data', false);
            } else {
                counter--;
                $(this).attr('data', true);
            }
            //$(this).end();
            count();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        .notification {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 9px;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            width: auto;
            min-width: 8px;
            height: 9px;
            line-height: 4px;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            background-color: #b60000;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="marketoptionslist">
     <a><button class="btn" data=true>
        click me
    </button></a>
    <a><button class="btn" data=true>
    click me
    </button ></a>
    <a><button class="btn" data=true>
      click me
     </button></a>
    <a><button class="btn" data=true>
      click me
    </button></a>
 </div>

 <span id="notify" ></span>
</br>
</br>
<button id="reset"> Reset Counter</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I use the attr() method as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: i tried this,but its still keeping my previous state and incrementing the value from where it stoped,i just want it to start all over from 1 again